# tqdm printing the multiple bar

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm trying to use the progress bar with tqdm

```
 progress_bar = tqdm(training_generator, position=0, leave=True)
            for iter, data in enumerate(progress_bar):
                if iter < step - last_epoch * num_iter_per_epoch:
                    progress_bar.update()
                    continue
```

Then the output looks like

```
[Info] initializing weights...
  0%|                                                                                                               | 0/787 [00:00<?, ?it/s]bbox_shape 0
Step: 2. Epoch: 0/20. Iteration: 3/787. Cls loss: 7.58472. Reg loss: 15.03549. Total loss: 22.62021:   0%|  | 3/787 [00:02<13:05,  1.00s/it]bbox_shape 0
Step: 4. Epoch: 0/20. Iteration: 5/787. Cls loss: 29.50139. Reg loss: 10.72687. Total loss: 40.22825:   1%| | 5/787 [00:03<10:21,  1.26it/s]bbox_shape 0
Step: 7. Epoch: 0/20. Iteration: 8/787. Cls loss: 1.49858. Reg loss: 25.04633. Total loss: 26.54491:   1%|  | 8/787 [00:05<08:40,  1.50it/s]bbox_shape 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try running the program from the command line? tqdm usually works better in the terminal as opposed to the idle.

Comment: i runned in terminal